# How to invoke EventEmitter's inherited function in another module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

```
//player.js

var inherits = require('util').inherits;
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

module.exports = Player;

function Player(uid, emailAddress, password) {
   this.uid = uid;
   this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
   this.password = password;

   EventEmitter.call(this);
}

inherits(Player, EventEmitter);

Player.prototype = {
   setUID: function(uid) {
     if(uid === 'number')
        this.uid = uid;
   },
   getUID: function() {
      return this.uid;
   },
   setEmailAddress: function(emailAddress) {
      this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
   },
   getEmailAddress: function() {
    return this.emailAddress;
   },
   setPassword: function(password) {
      this.password = password;
   },
   getPassword: function() {
    return this.password;
   }
}

// auth.js
var Player = require('./player');
var p = new Player(1000, 'someone@example.com', '12345');

// Here crashed
p.on('event', function() {
   console.log('Event emitted!');
});
p.emit('event');
```

I am new to Node.JS programming. I am trying to understand Node's EventEmitter module. However, when EventEmitter's `on(event, callback)` function is invoked in `auth.js`, it throws that error

```
TypeError: p.on is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/someone/App/libs/auth.js:7:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:425:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:146:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:540:3
```

I have no idea why it happens. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Your code works for me (just fixed a typo  `console.log('Event emitted!');` but this shouldn't be related to your problem. Which node version are you using?

Comment: I have edited the code. I think `Player.prototype` causes the error. @JohannesMerz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the prototype after the inheritance and loose all inherit functions:

```
function Player(uid, emailAddress, password) {
   this.uid = uid;
   this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
   this.password = password;

   EventEmitter.call(this);
}

inherits(Player, EventEmitter); // your prototype now contains things like, on, once, emit, ...

Player.prototype = {}; // => you overwrite your prototype and loose all methods that were on there before
```

So instead of overwriting, add your methods to the existing one:

```
Player.prototype.setUID =  function(uid) {
 if(uid === 'number')
    this.uid = uid;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! @JohannesMerz